# Set a date in an InfoPath form to null

Tags: infopath, xml, elements-xml

I'm trying to write an InfoPath form from code.

I'm working with the `xml` of a form, and when I write a date it gives me no error but when I open the form in SharePoint and click on Save, it says that the dates are not correct, exactly it says:

> Date Field "Only date allowed"

Note: I have tried with different formats and even that the format is the same that is showed if you choose a correct date.

Note: I use to write the `xml` element the next code:

```
writer.WriteElementString("my", "EntryDate",null, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Check the properties of the date control. Set data type to Text
>   (String) and change format to XML (Click format button and select
>   "None" option.

---

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53803456-c1f0-4a7e-91d0-c44df2965877/date-field-only-date-allowed?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: thanks Ali, but I prefer if possible not to change the data type, is ok being date.